# Not able to locate webelements of hybrid app using appium android in webview

Tags: java, android, appium, hybrid

I got the apk from developer, it is an ionic app. I could install apk and launch home screen successfully, switched to webview  but it didn't identify ids got through uiautomoviewer.

Every time I get error 'error locating elements'. Tried clicking anywhere was passed but can not enter any value in text fields or click on Show, Hide, Forgotpassword links.

Here is my script:

```java
    package com.prachi.tests;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
    import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

    public class login1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = Capabilities();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            System.out.println("Page Source: " + driver.getPageSource());

            Thread.sleep(20000);

            Set<String> context = driver.getContextHandles();
            Thread.sleep(20000);

            for (String Contextname : context) {
                System.out.println(Contextname);
            }
            driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.lodgistics.connect");

            driver.findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys("prachi.j");
            driver.findElement(By.id("user_password")).sendKeys("lodgistics123");
            driver.hideKeyboard();
            driver.findElement(By.id("Sign In")).click();

            // driver.findElement(By.id("lbl_forgotpass"));
            // driver.findElement(By.id("lbl_createacc"));    
        }

        public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> Capabilities() throws MalformedURLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

            File fs = new File("src/test/resources/app-debug (1).apk");
            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Nexus_5");

            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
            driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

            return driver;

        }
    }
```

All ids were identified through uiautomatorviewer but not able to locate when I run the script.
I also tried switching to Webview mode before login screen itself.

I have pasted [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m72ZK.png) in screenshot.

[image: 1]

Comment: did you tried chrome remote debugger for inspection ?
chrome://inspect/#devices

Comment: are you running this test on a real device or an emulator? I never managed to interact with webviews when I am running emulators with the play store installed, dunno if this can help.

Comment: Your dump of the DOM is not showing that those elements even exist, so this code would never have located those elements. Did you enable debugging in the webview (developer must do this for you)?

Answer (score 0):

It seem like, you wrong at the line:

```
driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.lodgistics.connect");
```

Use the bellow code:

```
Set<String> context = driver.getContextHandles();
driver.context(context.toArray()[1]);
```

Or:

```
driver.context("WEBVIEW_1");
```

[Docs](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason By.id() stopped working on new Chrome webview for me.

Try using `By.xpath("//*[@id='yourID']`

If that doesn't help try adding following capabilities:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("androidPackage", com.android.chrome);
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("androidActivity", org.chromium.chrome.browser.customtabs.CustomTabActivity);
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("androidUseRunningApp", true);
chromeOptions.addArguments("no-sandbox");
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
```

Comment: Did you ever find out why By.id() is not working.  I'm getting similar situation (with java).  I'm able to find elements with xPath, but not with ID.  Strange.